# Electron Application Menu Working Example

Tags: electron

I'm new to Electron and having problems finding a working example of an application menu.

When trying to combine the [Quick Start](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/) app with the example from the [Class: Menu](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/) page of the Electron Documentation, nothing seems to happen — chaning the `label` values has no effect.

Googling raises more questions than it solves — such as, do I need to package my application to effect change in the application menu, or do I need to move my `main.js` and `package.json` to `$projectRoot/resources/app` (and if so, do I need to package it to run it)?

Is there a better way to get the hang of Electron...?

#### Edit

When I add the below to my app on OSX, the Application menu has one entry — `Electron`, with one option, `Quit`:

```
const electron = require('electron');
var menu = electron.Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
        label: 'Electron',
        submenu: [
        {
            label: 'Options',
            click: function() {
                alert('Test');
            }
        }
        ]
    }
]);

electron.Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

Comment: hi i am also new to electron i am working on two apps with it one of them is this one https://github.com/thefailtheory/ANN-Stock-Prediction and i didn't try yet to display a menu because i use bootstrap instead

Comment: Upload your code to a GitHub repo if you want someone to help you figure out why it's not working as expected.

Comment: @LeeGee Are you calling `Menu.setApplicationMenu()` after the app emits the `ready` event?

Comment: @VadimMacagon — that solved the problem — MANY thanks, sir! Yes, it is obvious now....!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to package your app to change the application menu. Check that you're calling `Menu.setApplicationMenu()` after the `ready` event is emitted, e.g.

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
})
```

Comment: @LeeGee There are menu examples in the [Electron API demos](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos).

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to see whats the prb since you did not provide any code. However, here how this should work: In the main.js do this :

`var MenuItem = require('menu-item');`

And then make a function createMenu :

```
global.yourApp = {
        init() {
            whatsApp.createMenu();            
            config.init();
        },

        createMenu() {
            yourApp.menu =
                AppMenu.buildFromTemplate(require('./menu'));
                AppMenu.setApplicationMenu(yourApp.menu);
        }
}
```

./menu  you will have the menu.js file that should look something like this:

```
    (function(scope) {
        "use strict";

        var template = [
            {
                label: 'Edit',
                submenu: [
                    {
                        label: 'Undo',
                        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Z',
                        role: 'undo'
                    }
                   ......
              ]
    }]
})(this);
```

Comment: As a new user, I'm going to have to learn the difference between the library-declared symbols, and those you are using as indicators. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experienced:
"do I need to package my application to effect change in the application menu"?

Yes. This could be your root cause.

The default electron cmd includes the "chrome" of an application shell and does not utilize any included menu-altering code. You just get the default menu structure.

Comment: Only to change the menu name on OSX — "On macOS the label of the application menu's first item is always your app's name, no matter what label you set. To change it, modify your app bundle's Info.plist file. See About Information Property List Files for more information." — https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/menu.md